# How to centre modal for mobile device that's zoomed in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a modal that utalises the following function for centring the modal:

```
  center: function() {
     var top=Math.max($window.height() - $modal.outerHeight(),0) / 2;
     var left=Math.max($window.width() - $modal.outerWidth(),0) / 2;

     $modal.css({
        top: top + $window.scrollTop(),
        left: left + $window.scrollLeft()
     });
  }
```

This works fine for desktop and mobile devices when there is NO ZOOM applied to the screen. However as soon as the user zooms on a part of a screen and this function is called it calculates the wrong position and the modal is not long in the user's viewport.

Is there a way to make this function work on mobile despite the zoom? Alternatively I'm happy that i detected a mobile device and then just show the modal on the zoomed part of the viewport so at least the user seems the modal pop up.

Can any help with this as i'm stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the modal needs to always be centered on the screen, you could instead do the following with CSS alone:

```
/* adjust height/width properties to whatever you need them to be */
.modal {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I did have the modal absolutely positioned however I might moved to fixed positioned after seeing this. I'm still pondering the benefits of fixed vs absolutely positioned

Comment: fixed will make sure the modal always stays on top of the content of the page, where as absolute would allow page scrolling, and the modal would scroll with it.

I've written quite a bit about making accessible modal windows.  you can check out here: http://scottaohara.github.io/accessible_modal_window/

Comment: Thanks for that scott so do you recommend fixed instead of absolute?

Comment: it depends on what the intended user experience is meant to be.

e.g. if this is a modal that pops up and takes over the page and users shouldn't be able to interact with anything until it goes away. Then definitely.

if this is a modal that isn't a full page take over, then no. position absolute would be fine.